# Selecting options from input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, input

I'm making an application in Python which has a basic command line interface. The CLI is run in a continuous loop and the user is asked to select an option. The code is something like below:

```
def run(self):
  print("Menu: ")

  for key in sorted(self.options.keys()):
    print('  {}: {}'.format(key, self.options[key][0]))

  selection = input("Select an option: ")
  print('')

  if selection in self.options:
    try:
      self.options[selection][1]()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      pass
  else:
    print('Option not recognized')
```

Anyway, the *self.options* is a dictionary that is formatted like so:

```
{option: (description, callback)}
```

Here is the kicker. The code works perfectly on my computer which is sporting a Python 3.4, but it does not work for my coworker that has a Python 3.2 installed on his computer. Everytime he tries to run some option, he gets a 'Option not recognized'.

We did 'solve' the issue by installing Python 3.4 on his computer, but I'm still very intrigued by this and would like to know why it works on Python 3.4 but not on Python 3.2.

Thanks in advance,
Finnur

Comment: Are you guys using the same operating system?

Comment: Have you just tried inspecting what `selection` really is on the Python 3.2 install on your coworker's computer ? Using `pdb` or even a mere `print()` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour on Python 3.2.4; the callback gets called just fine for me. Does `self.options` contain the same values on both systems? Maybe there's some newlines tacked on -- does `selection.strip()` help?

Comment: @Kevin - Yes we're using Windows 7 Enterprise.

@brunodesthuilliers - A print statement tells us that `selection` is of type 'str' and appears to have the same value on both systems. I haven't used pdb though.

@nooodl: I'll check if that will do it if I get the chance.

Thanks for the suggestions guy's. I'll let you know if I get to the bottom of this, although it's not a priority at work :S